# How to pass a file locally without using input into Papa parse function

Tags: javascript, file, papaparse

I have a csv file in the same directory as my html file. I want to pass the location of the file into the Papa parse function.

I keep reading online, I can not assign the path to a variable for instance let a = "./discussions.csv" and pass directly

```
// trying to pass a into the file argument
Papa.parse(file, {
 complete: function(results) {
     console.log("Finished:", results.data);
 }
});
```

Could I use fs(filesystem).

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume since you mentioned `fs` that you are using node. And yes you would load the file into memory using `fs` and from there you would pass it to the papa parse function.

```
const file = fs.readFileSync(pathToFile, "utf-8"); 

Papa.parse(file, {
 complete: function(results) {
     console.log("Finished:", results.data);
 }
});
```

I used readfilesync for teaching purposes but please do replace it with the async version once you get this working.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I am not using node, but I want to try import require using the cdn link into my scriptand then use fs

Comment: Okay in that case you cannot use fs. If your file is coming from a cdn you are going to need to use fetch to bring the file into memory.

Comment: No, the file is in my directory but I want to use the require cdn link `https://cdnjs.com/libraries/require.js/` so I can be able to require('fs')

Comment: So for instance <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.min.js"></script>.So i can require the fs module and use the `readFileSync` or `createReadStream`

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, the `file` variable should be a [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object, which is meant for browser used.
You can however use readable stream, so something like this should work:

```
let fs = require('fs');
let file = fs.createReadStream('discussions.csv');

// trying to pass a into the file argument
Papa.parse(file, {
 complete: function(results) {
     console.log("Finished:", results.data);
 }
});
```